# Prevent Visual Studio Code from changing the window layout when the last file in a pane is closed?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, if I change my window's layout to include more than one pane (such as two columns), if I close the last file open in that pane then the entire pane will close and change the window layout. This is quite annoying! I always want there to be two columns, or whichever window layout I've set up.

Is there a way to change this behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to set this to false:

```
"workbench.editor.closeEmptyGroups": false
```

Then when the last editor of a group (or column as you say) is closed, that editor group will not close.